# wordpress wp-config hijacked, anyone can decode it what is running inside the code?

Tags: php, security, exploit

I notice something not right with my hosting, and I take a look into my wp-config there is some unknown code is added there. Anyone can decode / explain what is the coding doing for my server?

Here is the code:

http://laravel.io/bin/0zRe2#9

I manage to decode it until it run eval, create_function, base64_decode. After that I have no idea what is the code is doing. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a series of eval + Base64 encoding. The decoding process is relatively easy. If you look at the last line, you can see:

```
$idKTDNZxDpObOf3gyVJWUREvUEvaYuSMK3M($UuS9w2FD06i8R3aF7VSSFsjdONHd);
```

This is basically calling a function. To find out the actual PHP code being evaluted, simply echo the value of `$UuS9w2FD06i8R3aF7VSSFsjdONHd`. From the padding characters at the end of the output, you can easily make out that it's a Base64 encoded text. Decode that to ASCII text. Now change `eval` to `echo`. Rinse and repeat. Finally, you'd obtain  the [decrypted code](http://laravel.io/bin/kod6E).

By Googling the IPs in the code, I found [this article](http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/01/recent-optmizepress-vulnerability-being-mass-infected.html) which talks about an OptimizePress vulnerability. If your WordPress installation uses that theme, I suggest you delete the entire theme folder from `/wp-contents` directory and do a scan for more injected files. Optionally, contact the theme support for security fixes.

From a quick scan of the code, it looks like a backdoor that allows arbitrary PHP code to be evaluated, and files to be saved to your disk by exploiting WordPress' permissions. However, instead of worrying about what the code does, I suggest you find the vulnerability and fix it ***immediately***. Make sure you contact the hosting support (if you have one) as well.

Comment: ya, i am removed the code already. But I would like to know what is the code does to my other code, by reading the code. then I can know what it does to my code. Btw, the decrypted code diff like what I paste. Are you pasting the correct link?

Comment: @Shiro: Well, [this](http://laravel.io/bin/kod6E) is the link I have in the answer. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @Shiro: Added some more details about a theme vulnerability. See the edit.

Comment: Thank @Amal Murali, it really smart way to encode it.. it require repeat 3 times to see the original code... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shiro: Not *that* smart, given there are people that do `gzinflate(base64_encode(str_rot13(...` and even more to obfuscate the PHP code.